# In Ajax How to pass country name in html page to php page?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

> How to pass country name in html page to php page using ajax.

**demo.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Dynamic Form</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" ></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").on('submit',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

        data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "post.php",
        data: data
        }).done(function( msg ) {
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
        });
    });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<form>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<select name="one" onchange="if (this.value=='other'){this.form['other'].style.visibility='visible';this.form['submit'].style.visibility='visible'}else {this.form['other'].style.visibility='hidden';this.form['submit'].style.visibility='hidden'};"



<option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>
<option value="India">India</option>
<option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
<option value="Us">Us</option>
<option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
<input type="textbox" name="other" id="other" style="visibility:hidden;"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Country"  style="visibility:hidden;"/>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

</body>
```

**post.php**

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $Country = $_POST['other'];
    echo $Country;
}
?>
```

> When user select other from drop down list at that time display one
>   textbox and one submit button.when user click on submit button at that
>   time pass country name of demo.php to post.php using ajax.

Comment: `$_POST['submit']` is not going to be posted. Remove that. Also, you check for `$_POST` in PHP but define `GET` as your method in AJAX. So change one of the two and it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few errors. `$_POST['submit']` is never posted with the `data = $(this).serialize();`. So you need to check something else. 
Also, you define `GET` as your method in AJAX but check `$_POST` in PHP. So change one of the two.
Something like:

HTML / JavaScript:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dynamic Form</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" ></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("form").on('submit',function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                data = $(this).serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "post.php",
                    data: data
                }).done(function( msg ) {
                    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>

<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select name="one" onchange="if (this.value=='other'){this.form['other'].style.visibility='visible';this.form['submit'].style.visibility='visible'}else {this.form['other'].style.visibility='hidden';this.form['submit'].style.visibility='hidden'};">
                    <option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>
                    <option value="India">India</option>
                    <option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
                    <option value="Us">Us</option>
                    <option value="other">Other</option>
                </select>
                <input type="textbox" name="other" id="other" style="visibility:hidden;"/>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Country"  style="visibility:hidden;"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

</body>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['other'])) {
        $Country = $_POST['other'];
        echo $Country;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("form").on('submit',function(event){
var country = $("select[name=one]").val();
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'json',
url: "post.php",
data: { country:country},
success: function(json) {
}
    });
});
```